# Is there a better way to add line-breaks in a block of text than just putting <br> after every item?

Tags: html, css, formatting, break

I have a big list of items that are formatted like so:

```
list item <br>
list item <br>
list item <br>
list item <br>
list item <br>
list item <br>
```

etc.

Currently, I've got them to work by putting a `br` after every item, but it's kinda messy. Is there some CSS or HTML that I can use that will automatically break the line after each item? They are all currently inside a `p` tag.

Comment: Are these list items in either an ordered or unordered list block?

Comment: No, they can't be, otherwise you'd have the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: If they are list items, why using p tag instead of ul li or ol li

Comment: Mostly because laziness, aha. The list is dynamically increasing/decreasing and I don't know how to add an li dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to be using HTML's built in List tags, either an ordered or unordered list.

To answer your question, no, there is really no good solution to **breaking** a line, at least no other way that's easier than using the unordered `<ul>` or ordered `<ol>` list tags (or of course, simply using the `<br />` line break).

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t75j38kg/) that shows the basic functionality.

You can use CSS styling to tweak the display - so if you want the bullet points out, you'd add a CSS selector:

```
li { list-style: none; }
```

As shown here, in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t75j38kg/2/)

***EDIT****

Please note, the `<ul>` and `<ol>` tags have to be outside any `<p>` or inline tags.

Comment: Hm, ok, thanks. So it seems the only way is using li tags? Is there some way to automatically put li tags around a ton of text like that? I'm receiving the text as an unordered untagged list like in the post, will I just have to go and manually put li tags around each piece every time?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there's no easy way to do this with strictly CSS and HTML.  Maybe put the list in a text file, and use Javascript to read it line by line building your list?

Comment: Ok, thanks a ton, you answered my question. Maybe I'll look into the Javascript thing later but for now that's a bit above my skill level aha.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative would be to wrap each item in a block element, like this:

```
<div>list item</div>
<div>list item</div>
<div>list item</div>
<div>list item</div>
<div>list item</div>
<div>list item</div>
```

If your content is actually unordered list items, then use `ul` and `li` to be semantically correct:

```
<ul>
   <li>list item</li>
   <li>list item</li>
   <li>list item</li>
   <li>list item</li>
   <li>list item</li>
   <li>list item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `<br>` is not for breaking line. You can use br for example in this case:

`<p>`*Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. `<br>`

Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.* `</p>`

So good way is to use `<br>` tag for formating text inside paragraph. 
For breaking line use `<p>, <div>`  or other blocks elements.

Comment: <br> literally stands "break", as in "line break" -- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp